# Not able to click on device Menu button using Appium in Android

Tags: android, appium

I am working on automation of mobile native app using Appium in Java language. I want to click on device Menu button.

Method 1:

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("mobile: keyevent", 82);
```

tried but not working.

Method 2:-

```
HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap();
swipeObject.put("keycode", 82);
((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);
```

and

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: keyevent", {"keycode": 82})
```

this is not working, can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the menu button as `MobileElement` and use `tap()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Find the element by name and this should work :

```
driver.findElementByName("Apps").click();
```

Comment: It is a device specific menu bar...why "Apps".

Comment: Yes, find element by name and it should work. on most of the devices, menu button is named as "apps"

Comment: i wil check and let you know.

Comment: not sure what the problem is but u should check the locator and click on it thats it.